# how to minimize y in expression $(x^y) \bmod{n}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Let's consider $x^y\bmod{n}$.

$y$ comparing to $x$ and $n$ is veeeeeeeery big.
How can we minimize $y$ such that $(x^{\mathrm{newy}}) \bmod{n}$ gives same result as $(x^y) \bmod{n}$? What are the rules?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't "calculus", is it? I edited the tags but roll back if this is indeed from some esoteric calculus problem ;)

Comment: Thanks sir, didn't know in really what section place it

Comment: If $x$ is relatively prime to $n$, and it's multiplicative order mod $n$ is $ord(x)$, then you can add/subtract integer multiples of $ord(x)$ from $y$ without affecting the expression. (BTW is this homework?)

Comment: If $x$ is relatively prime to $n$, you can always reduce $y$ modulo $\varphi(n)$ (Euler's $\phi$). Of course, you may not know $\varphi(n)$ ahead of time (e.g., if $n$ is a product of two large but unknown primes).

Comment: Erm, why the tag rollback?

Comment: Homework ? We have holiday sir :)
But what if it's not relatively prime?

Comment: @Josh: I suspect it was an accidental side effect of a different edit. I changed back to the tags you had.

Comment: @Chris: If $x$ is not relatively prime to $n$, write $x=dz$ with $d=\gcd(n,x)$. Then $x^y = d^yz^y$; you can consider $z^y\bmod {n/d}$, which is the relatively prime case, and consider $d^y$ modulo $n$ separately; either $d^k\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for sufficiently large $d$, in which case $x^y\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for sufficiently large $d$, or else it will cycle among nonzero values and you can reduce. Then handle each part separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute $z = (x^y \mod n)$ using the *binary method* (also called *square and multiply*). The computational effort is $O(\lg_2 y)$. Then compute the partial products $x, x^2, ...$ until you get $x^e = z\mod n$. $e$ is the searched minimal exponent. The effort is $O(n)$ because there are at most $n$ different products.

Here is the algorithm in Python:

```
def binary(a):
    # returns binary represention of a, e.g. binary(6) = "110"
    b = ""
    while (a > 0):
        b = str(a & 1) + b
        a = a >> 1
    return b    

def minExp(x, y, n):
    # compute z = x^y mod n, effort O(lg y):
    b = binary(y)
    L = len(b)  
    z = 1
    for i in range(0, L): # O(lg y) steps
        z = z * z
        if b[i] == '1':   # i-th bit of b is set
            z = z * x
        z = z % n

    # find minimal exponent (effort O(n)):
    product = 1
    e = 0         # minimal exponent
    while product != z:
        product = (product * x) % n
        e += 1
    return e
```