# Simplified Exponent in $\bmod$ equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, modules, exponentiation

I am trying to simplified the following expression:
$$\left(y^m\right)^{x} \bmod p$$

In my case, I can only solve $(y^x) \bmod p$ first without prior knowledge of $m$. Eventually, my answer should derive at $(y^m)^{x} \bmod p$.

For example, $y^x \times g^m \bmod p = (y^x \bmod p \times g^m\bmod p ) \bmod p$

So I am asking, is there a way to simplify $(y^m)^{x} \bmod p$ like what I did for the above.

Comment: I did not get your question, what is the equation that you can solve? $a=y^x \mod p$? , $(y^m)^x \mod m$ is an "expression" not an equation, and the only possible simplification is $y^{mx}\mod p$

Comment: @Elaqqad hi, so sorry for the confusion. What I meant was I must eventually derive y^mx mod p. However, I must first solve y^x mod pm after which I will have the knowledge of m.

Comment: The issue is that there is no equation anywhere to be found, so it's highly unclear what you are trying to solve. It's like saying you want to solve 3.

Comment: @kenAu89, what i did not get is solving an expession, you said that : "solving the following equation :$(y^m)^x\mod p$" but actually this is not an "equation" ,it's an "expression".

Comment: hi guys! thank you all for the response and sorry for being vague to my question. I have found the following which is somewhat similar to the question I am asking. I will update should I find anything useful. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55098/how-to-minimize-y-in-expression-xy-bmodn?rq=1